# Performing a loop in windows command prompt for multiple netcdf files

Tags: loops, cmd, netcdf

I'm using a programm (andx) which allows me to extract data from a netcdf file into a .TXT file through the windows command prompt. Each ncdf file (370 total) have 7 variables (time, atmos_pressure, temp_mean, rh_mean, wspd_vec_mean, wdir_vec_mean and org_precip_rate_mean).

At the moment I'm able to perform what I want using each individual file by stating:

```
andx XXXXX.b1.20150401.cdf -o TXT atmos_pressure
```

This will output the time and teh variable atmos_pressure into a .txt.

I need to do this but for all 370 .cdf files that I have but I need to do a loop in the prompt. I'm trying to follow some tips from other treads in the forum and apply here:

```
FOR %i IN (*.cdf) DO andx *.cdf -o TXT atmos_pressure temp_mean rh_mean wspd_vec_mean wdir_vec_mean org_precip_rate_mean
```

I can see it searching each file but I'm getting an error saying that the variable is not found.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the prompt I'm working in a directory where I have the andx programm and the ncdf files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variable in the DO block.

```
FOR %i IN (*.cdf) DO (andx "%~i" -o TXT atmos_pressure temp_mean rh_mean wspd_vec_mean wdir_vec_mean org_precip_rate_mean)
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you Liturgist! Is there a way that I can do this and save in a unique .txt file since I now have to unify all 370 files into 1? Thanks

Comment: If this works, please mark it as the answer. If the `andx` program is naming the file as `XXXXX.b1.20150401.txt` and you want them gathered into `XXXXX.txt`, then please ask another question. Otherwise, I do not understand what you are seeking.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I just need to concatenate all 370 .txt files into one now since each one is a set of daily measurements. This way i would have a continuous recording of all measurements.

Comment: Please create a new question and tell how the .txt files are named.

Comment: I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695472/concatenate-txt-files-into-one-file-using-cmd-prompt