# Concatenate .txt files into one file using cmd prompt

Tags: cmd, concatenation

I have 367 .txt files that I need to concatenate into one big .txt file through the windows cmd prompt. Each file has the name and date on it, e.g.,

andx.20150401.000000.txt,
andx.20150402.000000.txt,
...,
andx.20160401.000000.txt

Inside each file I have 7 columns for time (in julians) and 6 other measurable variables. I need a continuous file for all 367 and I wanted to do this through the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do this as one command if the directory is clear of old files that might match the pattern.

```
TYPE andx.*.txt 2>NUL >>sum_file.txt
```

Alternatively, this could be built into a .bat script that produces the .txt files in your previous question. I doubt that you would want to type all this on the command line. Please note, this is not tested.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "SUM_FILE=xxxxx.txt"
IF EXIST "%SUM_FILE%" (DEL "%SUM_FILE%")

FOR %%i IN (*.cdf) DO (
    andx "%%~i" -o TXT atmos_pressure temp_mean ^
        rh_mean wspd_vec_mean wdir_vec_mean ^
        org_precip_rate_mean
    SET EXITCODE=!ERRORLEVEL!
    IF !EXITCODE! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO ERORR: andx failed processing "%%~i"
        ECHO ERORR: exitcode is !EXITCODE!
        GOTO TheEnd
    ) ELSE (
        FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE "%%~ni.txt"`) DO (
            ECHO>>"%SUM_FILE%" %%s
        )
    )
)

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Comment: Hi, the first choice (one code line) seems to work but I have a header in each .txt file that corresponds to the variables name in it. how can I apply that code line and concatenate all files without the headers?

Comment: I have edit the script to output lines after the first line in each file. Making that happen in a one-liner is difficult in DOS/Windows. It would be a piece of cake if you were on an OS that supported `tail`.

Comment: Thanks again, I solved that detail manually in the final .txt by punting in the beginning of each header "#" so it stays omitted when I'm using the data in R. Appreciated!